# What is the difference between Date(). and Date. in Swift?

Tags: swift, date, types

I mean generally speaking, what is the difference between using parentheses and not using them? Swift offers me different methods depending on whether I use Date(). oder Date.. I feel like it has something to do with type vs. objects or something but I don't know which keyword I should use for a proper Google search.

Comment: Date() creates a new instance, Date only is a class reference and is used for accessing class methods or properties

Comment: `Date()` is type instanciation (object creation), `Date` is the class/type name.

Answer (score 0):

Date(). accesses the object that the function Date() has created. Date. accesses the class of "Date" object

Comment: _"Date(). accesses the object that the function Date() has created"_ that makes no sense. `Date()` is not a function, it's shorthand for `Date.init()` and `Date()` doesn't access anything, it initialises a new `Date` object.

Comment: Doesnt Date.init() return it? Maybe I should edit the answer